# Mongodb double query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following MongoDb collection:

```
 {
     "id":1,
     "isBig": true } {
     "id":2,
     "isBig": true } {
     "id":3,
     "isBig": true } {
     "id":4,
     "isBig": true } {
     "id":5,
     "isBig": false } {
     "id":6,
     "isBig": false } {
     "id":7,
     "isBig": false }
```

I'd like to choose four random items: 2 should be big and 2 not. My attempt:

```
db.aggregate([
      { $match: { isBig: true } },
      { $sample: { size: 2 } }
    ]).toArray()
```

This choose only two big. I would need also two not big. COndition is I can access database only one time.

Comment: you can use `$facet` to have another pipeline for not big ones https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hq4KrZMyvVP